# SearchView widget isn't showing up on the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have been trying to put a SearchView widget on the Action bar, but it isn't showing up. I have tried the tutorial from google         http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html but nothing happens to the Action bar. Here is the code for further reference.

options_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

This is the code that I wrote in the Jave file of the Activity I want the  SearchView widget in.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

return true;
}
```

Minimum sdk = 14
Please Help!

Comment: Are you using `Theme.AppCompat`, `ActionBarActivity`, or `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: I'm using Hololight theme, extended ActionBarActivity. No I'm not using Proguard.